# How to return index of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list U of lists such that `U=[a[1], a[2], a[3]]` and where `a = [[0,1,2], [0,0,0],[1,1,1]]`.
I am trying to change U in a way that it will only contain lists without 2. I know that if I want  `U = [a[2], a[3]]` I have to do it like this:

```
for j in range (0,2):
    U= [f for f in U if f[j]!=2]
```

But now I want it to return  only the index of the lists, I mean  at the end U should be `[2,3]`.
Is it possible to do it ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> a = [[0,1,2],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(a, 1) if 2 not in x]
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
[i for i, j in enumerate(a) if 2 not in j]
```

note that list indices in Python start from `0`, not from `1`

Answer (score 0):

you can use index
`[U.index(l) for l in U if not 2 in l]`